# How do I get the sum of a matrix efficiently?

Tags: matrix

I have a problem in Python, I have a matrix that looks something like this: `[[2, 3, 5, 1], [5, 1, 6, 3]]`
and I tried using a for statement but that was too slow for my problem, what is an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What language? I'm pretty sure this can't be faster than O(N) ( where n = width * height ). and a for loop should be O(N) already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the numpy library to do this, a bonus is that numpy is extra fast than native Python, let me give you an example.

```
import numpy as np

matrix = [[2, 3, 5, 1], [5, 1, 6, 3]]
summedMatrix = np.matrix(matrix).sum()

print(summedMatrix)
```

Comment: OP did not share the language that he is using. Presumably, then, he is looking for generic pseudo code and a mathematical explanation, rather than a referral to a library in a specific language.

Comment: Sorry I forgot include it.